# Could not transfer meta data from local artifactory

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I use Maven to build a large number of projects.  I get the following error on several of the builds:

`[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata edu.uiuc.fs:aimutils/maven-metadata.xml from/to private-internal-repository (http://artifactory.fs.illinois.edu/artifactory/private-internal-repository): Not authorized`

It only happens when trying to pull metadata  actually pulling the Jars appear to work.
So, I assume this is not an account/password issue.

Working in a Windows environment, Maven version is 3.6.2.

How do I fix this problem?

Full trace below:

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata edu.uiuc.fs:aimutils/maven-metadata.xml from/to private-internal-repository (http://artifactory.fs.illinois.edu/artifactory/private-internal-repository): Not authorized
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata edu.uiuc.fs:aimutils/maven-metadata.xml from/to private-internal-repository (http://artifactory.fs.illinois.edu/artifactory/private-internal-repository): Not authorized
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.MetadataTransportListener.transferFailed (MetadataTransportListener.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Not authorized
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1145)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1094)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream (StreamWagon.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer (StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get (StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run (WagonTransporter.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute (WagonTransporter.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get (WagonTransporter.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: 1. Did you try with https?  If thats not the problem then 2. Make sure in settings.xml, apart from your correct userId/Password, the ids of  servers and mirrors are correct. Please refer the link if that can give you some hint. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569919/maven-getting-not-authorized-when-trying-to-access-nexus-private-repository

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Artifactory logs?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have right password configured. If the issue is intermittent, then you may try "*mvn clean install*".